# Can you square (or exponentiate to any power) both sides of a modular equation?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $ a \equiv b \;\;(mod\;p) $ then by definition this means $p | (a - b)$. Now for $n = 2$ we would have $ a^2 \equiv b^2 \;\;(mod\;p) $ or $p | a^2 - b^2$ and $p | (a - b)(a + b) $. Now this will also work for $n = 3$ and $ n = 4$. But what about $ n = 5 $? is there a factor of $(a - b)$ hidden in $a^5 - b^5$ ?

Comment: No. $a \equiv b \pmod p \Rightarrow p|(a-b)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that your symbols are backwards, and in each case you should have $p | (a - b)$, and so on.

---

In general,

$$a^n - b^n = (a - b)(a^{n - 1} + a^{n - 2} b + a^{n - 3} b^2 + \cdots + b^{n- 1})$$